# Understanding Matrix Addition Code and Usage of * Instead of & in Overloaded Operator Function

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to understand the following solution for a matrix addition problem:

```
class Matrix {
    public:
        vector<vector<int>> a;
        Matrix operator+(const Matrix& m) const;
};

Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& m) const {
    Matrix c;

    for (int i = 0; i < m.a.size(); i++) {
        vector<int> temp;

        for (auto j = m.a[i].begin(), k = a[i].begin(); j != m.a[i].end(); j++, k++) {
            temp.push_back(*j + *k);
        }
        c.a.push_back(temp);
    }
    return c;
}
```

In the code, I see the overloaded + operator function operator+() defined in the Matrix class. I'm having difficulty understanding the following line within the function:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& m) const {}
```

Why is it using * instead of & when passing the reference to m? I've tried using (*), but it doesn't work. Could someone explain why?

Additionally, if there is a more concise explanation or a better solution for this problem, I would appreciate it if someone could provide it.

Comment: Your question title says "how do I optimize this", but your question body is "please explain the solution to me". This looks like the standard form of an addition operator so what is there to explain that you textbook did not already?

Comment: If you want to optimize, measure (profile) your code and look for the bottlenecks (you might for example want to store your data in contiguous memory instead of seperate vectors wich can end up all over the place in memory).

Comment: "Why is it using * instead of & when passing the reference to m?" - what? Where is that code? I don't see that `*` which you are referring to. "I've tried using (*)" - where did you put that? "it doesn't work" - what is the error message?

Comment: Operator overloading is fools gold. This shiny feature lures beginners to early. When you first master basics of other parts of C++ then learning/understanding how to do operator overloading will take you literally 3 minutes. So please first learn, what is reference what is a pointer, what is a function, what is member function, ... .

Comment: `vector<vector<int>>` I don't think this definition makes a good matrix. A matrix should have a rectangular shape, right? `vector<vector<int>>` may give you a jagged array.

Comment: *'I'm having difficulty understanding the following line within the function'* – definition outside the class... Within the class, you only have a declaration. Now this line describes: `Matrix` = return type, `Matrix::` = scope resolution: this is a function of class `Matrix`, finally following function name (`operator+`) and function parameters as usual.

Comment: Read about pointers and references in your favourite C++ book. They are usually introduced well before overloading of operators.

Comment: In `auto j = m.a[i].begin()` `j` is an iterator. If you want the object referred to by the iterator you use `*`. This is to make the iterator look and behave more-or-less like a pointer

Answer (score 0):

`j` and `k` are auto variables and get the type of the `begin()` methods. Then the `*` is a dereference that returns the desired elements to be added.

Comment: Okay so what I understand from the matrix addition:
for a (ixj) matrix where i is the rows and j are the columns, M+N = (Mij + Nij) where M and N are two matrices.

How are we iterating rows and columns. I am facing issue understanding this snippet:
```
for (auto j = m.a[i].begin(), k = a[i].begin(); j != m.a[i].end(); j++, k++) {
            temp.push_back(*j + *k);
        }
```

Comment: @Mr.Unforgettable: apparently, you did not notice that I answered precisely about that.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by (*) you meant

> Why is it using * instead of & when passing the reference to m? I've tried using (*), but it doesn't work. Could someone explain why?

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix* m) const {}
```

The problem with this is, you would need to "+" addresses and not the Matrix. For example the * would work if you used the operator + as following

```
Matrix a, b;

/* insert some values in a and b */

Matrix c = a + &b (address of b)
```

This isn't the most logical thing to do, if you wanna add 2 Matrix's it should be just a + b and not  a + &b

Comment: I see now. One doubt I have left with me is that what is the proper way to say this function:
```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& m) const { ... }
```
I would be really helpful for me to search about this in the future.